# sendmail mail being recieved as user@ipaddress

Tags: linux, dns, ip, sendmail

A friend of mine has set up ("sendmail") and its receiving mail properly from his clients, however, the mail is showing up with IP addresses instead of FQDNs or domain names.

So instead of seeing From:User@domain.com, he sees From:User@address.

I've looked in his mail configuration file to see if he changed anything that he shouldn't have and aside from the changes he made for masquerading it is pretty much identical to the default file.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Fedorqui-He has masquerading setup that way in the sendmail.mc and its still giving him the ip address instead of the domain name. I've never encountered this issue before and Google isn't being very friendly towards my problem.

Comment: Have you performed last part of what my links comment? `Save and close the file. Replace domain name with your actual domain name. Update and restat sendmail server`

Comment: Yes, still didn't work out the way I wanted it to.  I just removed all of his configurations and rewrote them myself.  Works now.